# How to Compare the user Given date with the table date using Store Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have one date fields represents StartDate Using CalenderExtender and textbox field Represents ID. Im passing the 2 parameter from Code-Behind(ASP.NET) to Stored Procedure.....

IN the Table having 4 columns **ID,StartDate,Enddate and ReturntoWorkDate**:

My need is If i pass the parameter from Code-Behind it should compare with **StartDate, enddate** and **ReturntoWorkDate** and it should displays the record from the Table.

Examlple In the table **ID** : 001 **startdate** : 12-11-2010 **EndDate** : 12-19-2010 **ReturntoWorkDate** : 12-20-2010

i'm passing this parameters **ID** : 001 and **Startdate** : 12-13-2010

**OUTPUT:** 
**ID** :001 || **Startdate** : 12-11-2010 || **Enddate** : 12-19-2010 || **ReturntoWorkDate** : 12-20-2010

For Above Question **NEED STORED PROCEDURE ONLY**

This is the code.....

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchLeaveDate]
@employeeid varchar(30),
@leavestartdate varchar(30)

As
Begin
Declare @employee varchar(max)
declare @leavestart varchar(Max) 

select @employee = employeeid, @leavestart = leavestartdate from LeaveRequest where employeeid = @employeeid and (between leavestartdate >=@leavestartdate or leaveenddate <= @leavestartdate)

end
```

Can any one Help me please.............

Comment: Please post the code that is not working and any error message you have seen; they will help with answering your question.

Comment: You should at least provide with which technology you query your database like Linq2Sql, ADO.EF, Datatables, Datareader, ...?
Maybe you can post some code?

Comment: Normal Way only from ASP.net to SQLserver 2005

Comment: Define compare... you want records where startdate match, is before, after... ?

Comment: @Pauli : i want to compare each and every date. before or after function will work...

Comment: your query doesn't make sense. in 'where' condition, u use employeeID to compare which should be primary key. But why u need date comparison? And suppose if i need DateTime comparison, i'd pass datetime objext to databse, not varchar.

Comment: @Bonshington : yeah you are right but finally i Rearrange my query and found the Answer. Thanks for your Comments Friends..

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchLeaveDate]
@employeeid varchar(30),
@leavestartdate varchar(30)

As
Begin
Declare @employee varchar(max)
declare @leavestart Datetime

set @leavestart = @leavestartdate

select count(*) from LeaveRequest where employeeid = @employeeid and  (@leavestart  between leavestartdate and returndate) and (status = 'Pending' or status = 'Approved')

End
```